# GitHub API: using 'repo' scope, but still can't see private repos

Tags: authentication, github, github-api

Per the GitHub API docs, [I am requesting the **repo** scope which gives access to private repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).

The user is presented with the following dialog, which also mentions private repos. They accept the application.

[image]

Despite this, when using the oauth access token obtained when asking for 'repo' access, I can only see public repos when I GET **https://api.github.com/users/someusername/repos**. No private repos are shown.

The user account is my own, and I have not revoked access.

**How can I see private repos using the GitHub API V3?**

Comment: Which API endpoint are you calling exactly, and have you checked all pages? http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: @IvanZuzak Endpoint added above. My understanding was that pagination was only within repos, no, I'm not paginating GETting the list of repos, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From testing:

- GETing **/users/someusername/repos** doesn't show private repos (even if it's the user whose oauth access token you're using).
- GETing **/user/repos** show private repos.

This isn't documented in the [GitHub API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) at present, I just found out via testing.

Thanks to @ivanzuzak for suggesting to look at the endpoint.

Comment: @RyneEverett can you provide a link?

Comment: Still not seeing private repos at that URL

Comment: @matt Ask another question, mentioning you're using the correct `/user/repos` URL?

Comment: @Matt when issuing 'personal access token' you need to checkmark 'repo' access scope. Had the same problem. Dont know if it's possible to select lesser scope

Answer (score 6):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42qVr.png)

```
https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=#################################
```

this url gives all the public and private repositories, To get the token use this

`link https://github.com/settings/tokens`

Make sure you mark all the ticks given in the scope section

Comment: I don't see what this answers adds over the accepted self-answers by the OP.

Comment: Without marking the ticks in the scope section it did not work that why i answered like this

Comment: Github already deprecated this way of authenticating api requests.

Answer (score 3):

To access private information, you need to include the **access_token** parameter in the URL . Example:

/users/someusername/repos?**access_token=512295a0afb73bdd1c076a00c69f8abcd12345**

Access tokens are generated per user. You can generate your personal access token here:

https://github.com/settings/applications

You also need to have permission on the private repository to be able to see information about it.
You can also see information about the forks of the private repository that you have access to.

Comment: Not an answer. From the question: 'when using the oauth access token' - I am already using an access_token

Answer (score 2):

(I'm a newbie with Git and was using the command line following https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/ but I had trouble with quoting etc.  So I switched to using a browser and made some progress)

In the browser my url is

https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef

where I have swapped in fake token for my real one (tokens should be treated like passwords are not shared).

This gave me complete list of my private repositories in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

For any Octokit users having this problem: `client.list_repos(nil)` found [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/646#issuecomment-145614807) will use `GET /user/repos` which returns private repos too.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers don't help - I found that my PAT developer token needs to be authorized within that organization's single sign on.

0. Pass the pat token in your header (not in the url string)
1. Go to your tokens https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Click the Configure SSO button inline with your token
3. Authorize your token for the specific organization
4. You should now see private repos (but be sure to follow the link header for pagination purposes, Github's urls are not uniform)

[A picture of the SSO settings described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbsnz.png)