# How can I pull private repo data using GitHub API?

Tags: python, github-api

I am a member of an organization which has a lot of private repositories on GitHub. I need to use the GitHub API to get data from the private repositories. I am using the following python code:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/repos?access_token=[mytokenhere]"
headers = {"Authorization": "token [myPATHhere]"}
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers = headers)
content = response.text

my_json = json.loads(response.text)


for item in my_json:
    print(item['html_url'])
```

Where PAT = my access token. This still only returns the public repositories. I've seen the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907278/github-api-using-repo-scope-but-still-cant-see-private-repos) but the listed solutions do not solve my problem. Note that I've authorized my access token to get into the private repository. I've also tried api.github.com/users/repos and api.github.com/users/[myorghere] and still no private repos are returned. Am I not submitted the token correctly?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396329/how-to-download-github-release-from-private-repo-using-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your personal access token and ensure that you have selected the necessary scopes. The first one is for private repos so you may need to select some/all of the options there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code would work for an older version of the REST API.  However, when I tried accessing Github private repositories using the following code, it worked.

```
import requests

data = {"username": ""} # Put your username in the placeholder.
refresh_url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos"  # dont change, else error.
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN" #replace your token, and give necessary 
                                    # permission
}
user_data = requests.get(url = refresh_url, headers= headers, params=data)
# print(user_data.status_code)
# print(user_data.json()[0])
for repository in user_data.json():
    print(str(repository["full_name"]) + " -> " + str(repository["private"]))
```

Comment: Commenting to say that I tested and verified the same.