# Can't access git private repos using personal access token even though I have given it all the scopes

Tags: git, github

This is the response header I get
I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
enteContent-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Status →200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit →5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining →4997
X-RateLimit-Reset →1551418998
Cache-Control →private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary →Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
ETag →W/"4565984787f6361e646a393a316ef814"
X-OAuth-Scopes →admin:business, admin:gpg_key, admin:org, admin:org_hook, admin:public_key, admin:repo_hook, delete_repo, gist, notifications, repo, user, write:discussion
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes →
r code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your PAT is actually *not* used (because your credentials, with a regular password) might already be cached by a credential helper see git config credential.helper)

Or you are not using the right user when trying to access the repo (and that session, with a different account) would not find your regular Git settings.

Or you are not using the right URL (because it might be rewritten by a [`url.<base>.insteadOf` config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf)

The [OP Manu Poduval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10003490/manu-poduval) confirm [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938200/cant-access-git-private-repos-using-personal-access-token-even-though-i-have-gi/54938619?noredirect=1#comment96641954_54938619) the URL issue, but it was actually an API URL, as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909135/6309):

> - GETing `/users/someusername/repos` doesn't show private repos (even if it's the user whose oauth access token you're using).
> - GETing `/user/repos` show private repos

Comment: i was using the worng GET path 
GETting /user/repos?access_token = "xxxx" gets all the repos
I didn't find this anywhere in the api docs but I found this on another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907278/github-api-using-repo-scope-but-still-cant-see-private-repos

Comment: @ManuPoduval Good catch. I have included that cause in the answer for more visibility.